# Usage of "[Name] of [Company]"

Tags: names, archaicisms, nicknames

I believe I've heard a phrase such as

> Steven Stevenson of Microsoft

or

> Kylie Kyleson of StackExchange

How frequent is it to refer to someone in this way, or in other words, does it sound too pretentious, or is it a valid way to add credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a valid way to refer to a person.

However, it implies that the company name in question is *sufficiently well-known*, and is also relevant to establishing their credentials *for the topic under discussion*.

So, if we were discussing Active Directory, then referring to someone as "Joe Bloggs *of Microsoft*" gives weight to their opinion; but "Sid Smith of Starbucks" is probably pointless.